# pmax/pmin in scalar_tanh_op in eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I know SSE2 optimization will packet complex numbers 4 by 4, but it's still complex number, so It must need max/min operator, but where is max/min operator for complex number

Comment: `std::abs(std::complex<T>)` returns the magnitude, a T, (vector length) of a complex number. You can then use max().

Comment: one of eigen's developer says complex number will not be packet